Contraction mapping theorem for statistical self-similarity
The notion of self-similarity that I was given is the following:
Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and for each $1 \leq i \leq N$, let $f_i: X \rightarrow X$ be a contraction. Then there exists a unique non-empty compact subset $K$ of $X$ that satisfies
\begin{align}
   K = f_1(K) \cup ... \cup f_N(K) .
  \end{align}
$K$ is called self-similar set w.r.t. to $\{f_1, ..., f_N\}$.
For self-similar shapes like the Sierpinski triangle I have a feeling what the compact set looks like and in what way the $f_i$'s act on such a set. Then I came across the notion of statistical self-similarity, which states that a objects statistical properties don't change on different scales. How does this connect to my "definition"? What's the metric space, what's the compact subset and how do the $f_i$'s look like in the case of statistical self-similarity?

Where does this definition come from?  It seems to include a lot of things which are not self-similar (e.g. self-affine sets, such as Bedford-McMullen carpets), and also seems to be putting the cart before the horse.  The theorem you cite, which can be found in Hutchinson's 1981 paper, only asserts that an iterated function system has a unique, compact attractor.  Self-similarity is a somewhat more restrictive notion.

@XanderHenderson Thanks, this was given to me through a set of lectures notes on Geometry and Fractals. I now understand that this condition is incomplete and got the correct one from Hutchinson's paper. My question still remains the same if one can even formulate it in that way.  Hutchinson even mentioned in said paper that there will be a follow up to define statistical self-similarity, I couldn't find one however.
